# How to deploy ASP.NET project?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, webforms, windows-server-2008, webdeploy

I've got an ASP.NET Webforms project created in Visual Studio 2013 on my local computer, it's plugged into SVN. I've been asked to find a couple different options for migrating the project to a machine running Windows Server 2008 R2 and deploying it using IIS.

So far I've tried following [this article](http://www.itworld.com/article/2833419/consumerization/if-you-re-developing-in-visual-studio-and-not-using-webdeploy--you-re-doing-it-wrong.html) on Web Deploy. I was able to get all the way through it, verify that the connection worked, and it said the application was published, but I was unable to view it in a browser (not really sure how to setup a test URL properly using this method or what exactly happens when I publish).

I've been told that FTPing it to the server using Visual Studio is not so ideal, and that somehow using Subversion to copy it over to the server might be best.

**What is a hassle-free, secure way to publish this project via the server?**

I know basically nothing about networks, servers, and publishing sites, so any ideas/help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a useable solution for my own problem. Here's what I did in case anyone else needs help:

1) In IIS, on server machine, browse to the inetpub folder, right click on it and share the folder with the machine hosting the VS project.

2) In Visual Studio, select VISUALSVN->RepoBrowser. Rightclick on the trunk folder (it should contain the project folder) and select export. Use the 2nd … button to select the now shared folder on the server by selecting it in the network tree.

3) In IIS, right click on sites. Select add new website. For site name, enter the name of the project, and for application pool select ASP.NET v4.0. Set physical path to folder that was shared earlier. Don’t setup any binding for now. Click Ok.

4) Explore the project folder, right click on it. Properties -> Security tab ->Edit->Add. Click the location button. Select host machine at the top of the tree. Add entries for “IUSR” and “IIS_IUSRS” both with full permissions using this method. This will allow IIS to deploy the site properly.

5) In IIS, select the site on the sidepanel. Double click the Default document icon. Add an entry at the top for the .aspx page you want it to start with.

6) Start and browse to the website.